# How frequently does one need to recite Shehakol when drinking?

Tags: blessing

It was widely reported in yesterday's news that one of President Trump's impeachment lawyers covered his head with his hand and recited a *bracha* every time he took a sip from his water bottle.  It has always been my understanding that once you have recited *Shehakol* once you do not need to keep reciting it for each sip.  Perhaps I have been doing it wrong all these years?  Of course, after a sufficiently long interval of time the action you are no longer "covered", so to speak.  What criteria determine how frequently one must recite *Shehakol* when drinking?

Comment: Usually only leaving the room/vicinity or saying a concluding after blessing would "end" the "scope" of the initial blessing. I can't comment about what any of the lawyers was doing, not having seen or spoken with any of them.

Comment: @DoubleAA Presumably time matters, too. If I have a sip of water before bed and then sleep 8 hours, my bracha is no longer operative when I wake up, right?

Comment: Going to sleep is marking the end like saying an after blessing

Comment: He wasn't making a Bracha each time, despite the news reports otherwise. They misunderstood what he was doing by covering his head when he drank.

Comment: @robev Are you sure? I was not aware that covering the head is necessary when drinking, *per se*. It's the *bracha* that triggers the need for the *kippah*, no?

Comment: I didn't say if it was necessary. I'm saying he wasn't saying a Bracha. [This](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/14793) seems to forbid eating without covering one's head